# different position of caret in textarea when empty / have text

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, textarea

I have a problem with `<textarea>`. Caret in it has different vertical position based on when it's empty or not:

[image]

**my code:**

```css
textarea {
    padding: 0 5px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 30px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 26px;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

**demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/oapbghfs/

Comment: Why aren't you using a text field for one line rather than a text area? Also, FYI you have outline declared twice.

Comment: It's only basic height of this textarea. I have JS which makes it bigger when user typing in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This makes your text align:

```
textarea {
    padding: 5px;
    border: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    vertical-align: middle;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

It's a text area and it has two lines by default.

A height of 15px will make it look like it's one line and then you can remove and resize the area with JS.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you have your line height set to 26px.

I don't think theres any way to set the starting caret position other than with padding, but you'd run into the same jumping problem if your line-height needs to be so large. If the text area is required you could try to use the `:invalid` pseudo selector to target the empty textarea and fiddle with the top padding to get the desired position.

Also right now your border constricts on focus. That is because you are using outline to set your red border. Not sure if this is the desired effect, but using border instead will make it not constrict on focus.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove your line-height style, the caret becomes consistent.

Comment: But how to center it verticaly then?

Comment: Are you willing to change the height? 
    height: 18px;